# Get name of last object when drawn

Tags: mql4, mql

I have an EA that draws an object on a chart every 5 minutes
I need a loop code that gives me the name of the last object when it is drawn
I'm beginer for coding. Can you guide me for that code ?
Thanks a lot.
I don't know what code i can to write.